Errors when trying to mount an EFS file system on AWS EC2 Linux/Unix instance - package management tools 2024
I hope someone can help:
I'm trying to mount an efs on my Linux/Unix AWS EC2 instance, using:
sudo mount -t efs -o tls fs-0e1f111ff1fff11d1xe1:/ efs

I get:

mount: /home/ec2-user/efs: unknown filesystem type 'efs'.

I suppose to install first the efs utils, and as far as I know from 2023 is no longer using yum but dnf
When I try that: sudo dnf install amazon-efs-utils
I get the following error:

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo dnf install amazon-efs-utils
Amazon Linux 2023 repository
0.0  B/s |   0  B     06:00 Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'amazonlinux':
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'kernel-livepatch': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://al2023-repos-us-xxx-2-dexxxdc2.s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/kernel-livepatch/mirrors/al2023/x86_64/mirror.list [Connection timeout after 30001 ms]
Ignoring repositories: amazonlinux, kernel-livepatch
No match for argument: amazon-efs-utils

I've been looking for a solution for this, but whatever I find leads me to the same issue, and I always get 'time out'.
I'd appreciate any suggestion, thanks
Miinch
